# Why does one typescript declaration break another?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I have two `declare module` statements seen below

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import type { DefineComponent } from "vue";
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
    export default component;
}

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
    import { Auth0Plugin } from "@/auth";

    export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $auth: typeof Auth0Plugin;
    }
}
```

Individually they both seem to work as intended, but when they are both declared I get the error shown below

[image]

Why am I unable to have both of these typescript declarations - how can I modify my code to be able to use both?